# How to get value of mat-chip in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to call a typescript function from an angular html page. I want to pass a parameter in the function.  The parameter will be a boolean of whether or not a mat-chip is selected.  I've googled it but can't find solution.  Any ideas?

```
<mat-chip-list>
  <mat-chip [selected] = "isActive">Active People<mat-chip>
  <mat-chip [selected] = "!isActive">Inactive People<mat-chip>
<mat-chip-list>

<button mat-icon-button >
  <mat-icon aria-label="download" (click) = "doSomething(value-of- 
  chip1)>get_app</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: Where's your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you already have a variable, can't you pass that in?

```
<mat-chip-list>
  <mat-chip [selected]="isActive">Active People<mat-chip>
  <mat-chip [selected]="!isActive">Inactive People<mat-chip>
<mat-chip-list>

<button mat-icon-button >
  <mat-icon aria-label="download" (click)="doSomething(isActive)>get_app</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: Ah, I'll try that.  I'm so new to Angular (inherited from someone else) that I didn't even know that a string gets turned into a variable name.  So I'm curious what will be passed, the string "isActive" or the boolean true or false.

Comment: The boolean, if this sort of concept seems really foreign I suggest maybe running through the angular tutorial on their site.